# The sampling frequency or sampling period for financial time series in doing DFT

Tags: signal-processing, fourier-transform, spectral-analysis

The discrete Fourier transform (DFT) is widely utilized in computer engineering, and its formula is as follows:
$$X(k)=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x[n]e^{-i\frac{2\pi}{N}nk},$$
where the result $X(k)$ refers to the Fourier coefficient and it reveals the amplitude and phase at each frequency.
I try to apply DFT or FFT to financial time series, and most financial time series are daily data. I have a question in drawing the frequency-amplitude gram, I know the amplitude for $k$th frequency is $\frac{1}{N}|X(k)|^2$, but calculate the frequency needs sampling period or sampling frequency, how can we define the sampling period or sampling frequency for daily financial time series? Thanks!